# Serve html files Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, httpserver, windows-rt

I'm trying to run a StreamSocket to serve html, js, css and image files in order to present content that's been extracted from a zip file in my WebView (I'm developing with Windows Phone 8.1 Universal XAML apps)

I've tried to tweak the code that's in the question asked here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150024/in-process-http-server-dies-in-released-windows-8-app

But it's just not working, what I mean by that is nothing is being shown on the webview.

Is there a sample or has anyone tried doing this in Windows 8 RT or Windows Phone 8.1 apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create your own webserver to display local files in a WebView.
You can just pass the relative path of the html file you extracted from the ZIP.

Comment: How would that be possible if I can't reference a path in LocalStorage?

Comment: How come you can't reference the path? Could you update your question with some sample code that shows how you're extracting the zip file?

Comment: Tim Heur writes that <WebView Source="ms-appdata:///local/myfolder/mypage.html" Width="600" Height="400" /> is supported in 8.1. More information at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3e759487-ea22-4ea6-8096-ff013fb099fd/how-to-load-a-local-htmlfile-into-webview?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you can't navigate to a downloaded HTML file or execute scripts in the WebView. The solution for this could be an in-process HTTP server as given here:

[Loading Local HTML Content in Metro WebView](http://blog.jsolutions.co.uk/?p=492)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case anymore in Windows 8.1. See the bottom of this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3e759487-ea22-4ea6-8096-ff013fb099fd/how-to-load-a-local-htmlfile-into-webview?forum=winappswithcsharp